# Is There Mustache Syntax Highlighter Or Plugin For NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, syntax, mustache

There are such thing as [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/). I'm using NetBeans and I need to edit *.mustache* files. The problem is that when I open it using NetBeans, syntax is just like for plain text.

1) Is it possible to have HTML-like syntax for *.mustache* files?

2) Is there any plugin that allows to work easier with Mustache? I have found only [this tutorial](http://wiki.netbeans.org/SyntaxColoringANTLR).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seemes that the way described at the link you've posted is
only way: write your own plugin for netbeans (it's quite difficult task)

1) Follow http://wiki.netbeans.org/SyntaxColoringANTLR

2) But the more difficult thing is to implement your language definition as an embedded one.

It's needed if you want to highlight mustache template tags inside other language files (html, xhtml)

In older versions of NetBeans was a really simple api and module (it cannot be itegrated with all the platform services, like refactoring and so on) but it was based on grammar definition (BNF or something like that) and color  scheme for tokens.

Answer (score 12):

If creating your own plugin is to hard, you might be already content if mustache templates are displayed as (normal) HTML instead of plain text.

This can be configured in Options > Miscellaneous > Files. Create a 'New' file extension named 'mustache'. Than select 'HTML Files (text/html)' as associated file type.

Comment: Better text/x-twig

Answer (score 2):

I think better is to open this files as text/x-twig.